# How does one make javac use a .jar's classes?

Tags: java, bash, compilation

I am studying (cramming) for the AP Computer Science test. One of the requirements is the need to familiarize oneself with a program called "GridWorld." In my studies, I have been running and compiling my code using the terminal, instead of an IDE. In one directory, there is a program called BugRunner.java that must be compiled. The classes are in a .jar file called gridworld.jar. Gridworld.jar is in a separate directory. How do I configure the javac compiler to use the classes? I use a Mac with a bash shell. I tried typing

```
javac -cp .:/Users/raidenworley/programming/java/apcomp/GridWorldCode/projects/firstProject/gridworld.jar BugRunner.java
```

into the terminal, but I then receive the following:

```
BugRunner.java:17: package info.gridworld.actor does not exist
import info.gridworld.actor.ActorWorld;
                           ^
BugRunner.java:18: package info.gridworld.actor does not exist
import info.gridworld.actor.Bug;
                           ^
BugRunner.java:19: package info.gridworld.actor does not exist
import info.gridworld.actor.Rock;
                           ^
BugRunner.java:33: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActorWorld
location: class BugRunner
        ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld();
        ^
BugRunner.java:33: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActorWorld
location: class BugRunner
        ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld();
                               ^
BugRunner.java:34: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Bug
location: class BugRunner
        world.add(new Bug());
                      ^
BugRunner.java:35: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Rock
location: class BugRunner
        world.add(new Rock());
                      ^
7 errors
```

Comment: If this was eclipse, simply right-clicking the project and getting configure-path tab in then choosing "add external jar". Otherwise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079635/how-can-i-set-the-path-variable-for-javac-so-i-can-manually-compile-my-java-wor gives some results.

Comment: That's all in windows, which I don't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to the jar within your -cp since I didn't see it.

You can do it by exporting out your class path.

Take a look here

[adding classpath in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580860/adding-classpath-in-linux)

As you have mentioned you was referring to the path containing java file rather than jar.

You should be able to refer your folder containing the jar without calling physical jar. I only said this to ensure it was available. Anyhow if you wish for advanced methods of exporting class paths. Useful fir auotmated cron calls etc have a read of this [Can I export a variable to the environment from a bash script without sourcing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618071/export-a-variable-to-the-environment-from-a-bash-script-without-sourcing-it)

Comment: The jar is referred to. The classpath is /Users/raidenworley/programming/java/apcomp/GridWorldCode/projects/firstProject/gridworld.jar

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. I typed into the terminal:

```
 javac -cp .:../../gridworld.jar BugRunner.java
```

And then ran it using

```
java -cp .:../../gridworld.jar BugRunner
```

I don't understand what was wrong, or why this worked.

Comment: Oh I know why, the path I typed into the terminal the first time is the path of the .java file, not the .jar file. Wow *facepalm*

Comment: Lol told you I didn't see the jar file in youe classpath. :-)