# How to set external jars while runing executable jar through command prompt on linux

Tags: java, linux, spring, jar

I am running below command
/opt/java/bin/java -jar /opt/tools/java/service.jar

and I am getting below error
The java class is not found:  org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run Java program in terminal with external library JAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949413/how-to-run-java-program-in-terminal-with-external-library-jar)

Comment: export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:foo.jar:../bar.jar"   sources : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580860/adding-classpath-in-linux

Comment: This question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922681/differences-between-java-cp-and-java-jar